# cannot change API_OPENIM_PORT

Tags: docker

afterI changed API_OPENIM_PORT according to file, I got error
{
"errCode": 500,
"errMsg": "Post "http://172.28.0.1:40002/auth/user_token": read tcp 172.28.0.9:59842-\u003e172.28.0.1:40002: read: connection reset by peer",
"errDlt": ""
}
It should work for log in

Modify .env and config files to change API_OPENIM_PORT to 40002 then docker compose up -d, build, start, and check. All checks will pass. After that, try creating an account and logging in

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. In order to modify the internal and external ports of the existing docker-compose, we need to address the lack of Nginx for both the ws and api web services. As a result, the web service is currently inaccessible and requires testing on a PC.